# Apache spark Graphx :GraphLoader minEdgePartitions selection

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

Is it good to change the minEdgePartitions when using the GraphLoader function and if so why ; I would like also to ask what number to choose based on cpu and memory.
Much appreciated.